# Modal popup send values to parent window for dialog opened using SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, popup, modal-dialog

Sharepoint promoted links webpart open in dialog opens the popup using `SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowPopupDialog(url)`. I am closing the pop using  `SP.UI.ModalDialog.commonModalDialogClose(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK)` . But I want to redirect the parent window to a url which is to be sent from modal popup. But promoted links doesn't send object to return value in `dialogReturnValueCallback`. Is there a way where we can still redirect the parent page to a url?

Comment: you can do setTimeout and change the window.location.. is it ok for you?

Comment: The url value should save only when return value from popup is ok else nothing should happen

Answer (score 0):

You can send value to parent using QueryString. Modal send IsDlg param in QueryString when window is closing and in ServerSide you can redirect to other side.

Maybe here you can find help http://vimleshtiwari.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-close-sharepoint-modal-dialog.html